# Is it possible to create a Multi-lingual List Definition in a SandBox

Tags: list-template, sandbox-solution, localization

I have a sandbox solution that for the some of it I have german translations for, like the feature name and description.

However to make this a proper multi-lingual solution I need to do the same for the List Definition.

But I think, I'm pretty sure that the list Definition will not referefence the feature resource files, the only way to localise a sandbox I think.

So have  I got the wrong end of the stick.

Is is possible to have alternate language for a list definition (field titles, list name etc) in a sandbox.

If So how?

To clarify a little more.

I can create the list in XML or Code. But in order for the list to be language specific at runtime, ie when a user switches langauges, the field names and list name must have a specific "$Resouce" entry against them.  If I leave it without a dll prefix as you would for feature resources, it does not work.  Lists work a little differently it seems.

So What I want to know is What $Resouce should I be using, if you are using Satellite assemblies then whats the entry in the list def you use.

Admittedly I have not tried satellite assmeblies yet as I wasnt sure about deploying them in the sandbox, so the articles on how to do this are of interest. This might work, I was hoping someone had done this.

Comment: I've asked a similar question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30967/sandbox-content-type-and-resource-resx-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a very good MSDN article about localizing SharePoint Sandboxed solutions:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615460.aspx

If you will unable to perform localization through XML, take a look at a code approach: we've done this in a real project, works fine and it is easy to maintain.

You will need to know:

- [SPWeb.Lists.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.add.aspx) - create list programmatically
- [SPList.Fields.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472869.aspx) - add field to a list programmatically
- [SPUserResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuserresource.aspx) - class where SharePoint stores localization values
- [Retrieving resources from satellite assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70s77c20.aspx) (MSDN article)

Ok, this way you will have to write some code, but trust me, this is much better approach, then unpredictable and type-prone XML, especially when you have many custom lists.

Feel free to ask any futher questions, if you'll decide to go this way.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.  The msdn docs are new to me, well everyone as they are dated in feb I've been looking at this on and off since december.
I've added more clarification to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

A first peek into this (As I will need to do something similar later this year) yields looking into Satellite Assemblies. First time I've even heard of this concept, but it looks like you compile your resx files into public classes, and reference them in your code as strongly typed objects.

http://www.mikhaildikov.com/2007/06/using-satellite-assemblies-in.html

Comment: I will give that a try. I already use compiled resources in my 2007 farm projects all the time, its how my 2007 list defs are multilingual. 

For anyone interested the blog post says you cant use the <%$Res in aspx pages, which is true but in code you can populate a label control by accessing the resource variable string directly.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends how you're going to deploy this. But if you do go the Satellite Assembly route then I doubt it would work in a SandBox; since the assembly must be deployed on the web frontend itself.

Site variations however, may work.

Comment: thanks but this is for a standard solution not using variations